# How can I add animation to react state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, react-animations

I just want to add a fade in animation to next index. i found a package called "react transition group" but all tutorials were based on class components or redux I didn't understand anything.

[image]

```js
const AboutTestimonials = () => {
  const [index, setIndex] = useState<any>(0);
  const [data] = useState(AddTestimonial);
  const current = data[index];

  return (
    <div className="testimonials__container">
      <div className="testimonials__description">
        <h3>TESTIMONIALS</h3>
        <p>{current.quote}</p>
        <h5 className="author__testimonials">{current.postedby}</h5>
        <h6 className="job__testimonials">{current.profession}</h6>
      </div>
      <div className="testimonials__pagination">
        <Image
          src={leftarrow}
          alt="arrow"
          onClick={() => setIndex(index > 0 ? index - 1 : index)}
          className="pagination__arrows"
        />
        <p>{index + 1} / 5</p>
        <Image
          src={rightarrow}
          alt="arrow"
          onClick={() => setIndex(index < 4 ? index + 1 : index)}
          className="pagination__arrows"
        />
      </div>
```

Comment: add the map function to the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SwitchTransition` waits for the old child to exit then render the new child as mentioned in the [react transition group website](http://reactcommunity.org/react-transition-group/switch-transition).
there are two modes:

1. in-out
2. out-in

the important factor is changing the key prop of the child component.child component could be `CSSTransition` or `Transition`.if you want the transition changes simultaneously you can use the `TransitionGroup`.

> side note: if you want to use the `AddTestimonial` in your component and you don't want to change the state (I noticed there is no second argument for setting the data), there is no need to declare a `useState`.it is much better to set `AddTestimonial`  as a prop on `AboutTestimonials` component

```js
import { CSSTransition, SwitchTransition } from 'react-transition-group';
const AboutTestimonials = () => {
  const [index, setIndex] = useState<any>(0);
  const [data] = useState(AddTestimonial);
  const current = data[index];

  return (
    <div className="testimonials__container">
      <div className="testimonials__description">
        <h3>TESTIMONIALS</h3>
        <SwitchTransition mode={'out-in'} >
         <CSSTransition
           key={index}
           timeout={300}
           classNames="fade"
           >
          <>
           <p>{current.quote}</p>
           <h5 className="author__testimonials">{current.postedby}</h5>
           <h6 className="job__testimonials">{current.profession}</h6>
          </>
         </CSSTransition> 
       </SwitchTransition>
      </div>
      <div className="testimonials__pagination">
        <Image
          src={leftarrow}
          alt="arrow"
          onClick={() => setIndex(index > 0 ? index - 1 : index)}
          className="pagination__arrows"
        />
        <p>{index + 1} / 5</p>
        <Image
          src={rightarrow}
          alt="arrow"
          onClick={() => setIndex(index < 4 ? index + 1 : index)}
          className="pagination__arrows"
        />
      </div>
)}
```

css:

```
.fade-enter {
  opacity: 0;
}
.fade-enter-active {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity 300ms;
}
.fade-exit {
  opacity: 1;
}
.fade-exit-active {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 300ms;
}
```